# Getting connection error if made httprequest from my production server to other production server , but its done with localhost

Tags: python, api, python-requests, remote-server

```sh
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='remoteapiserver', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/post (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7feb54060bd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110]Connection timed out',))
```

code :

```py
import requests
import json

url :"https://remoteapiserver.com/api/post"

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

datas = {"foo":"bar"}

r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(datas),headers=headers)
```

hidden the url and domain

both `POST` and `GET` are getting same error.

Comment: Just `ping` your `remoteapiserver` and update the answer please.

Comment: hi kushan ping is working with remoteapiserver , thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `url` value. Something wrong with the python syntax and the formatting of your `URL`. It should be `<protocol>://<server>/<context path>/<type>/<path>`, please check this [link](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Architecture/URL%20Architecture/Standard%20URL%20Format/) for further more about `URL` formatting.

```py
url = 'https://www.remoteapiserver.com'
```

Comment: hi kushan , every thing is fine with the url and the procedure . just now I have tried the same thing using amazon ec2 instance , the request is successful . but before  i have tried with digitalocean instance , which resulted in failure of request. Thanks you for your concern dude

Comment: you're welcome @pythonista and It's happy to hear you solved your problem.